# Moins que jamais

Tags: négation, comparatifs

J'ai rencontré la phrase :

> Moins que jamais ces pays ne sont prêts à renoncer à une intégration nucléaire.

Pourquoi moins que et pas plus que ? Est-ce une faute ?

Comment: In languages other than English the negative alignment of a phrase is much stronger without incurring problems like the double negative. Hence "il n'y a ni rien ni personne qui ..." My reading is thus that as they are *not* ready, the preferred comparative is the negative one.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Merci pour le commentaire. Je comprends mieux maintenant:-)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a mistake!

It is a case of expletive *ne* that non native French speakers often confuse with a double negative.

A real double negative would have been:

> Moins que jamais, ces pays ne sont pas prêts...

*Moins que jamais* (less than any other circumstance) is the negation of the adverbial expression *plus que jamais* (more than any other circumstance, i.e. more than ever). There is no *less than ever* in English though.

The *ne* in *ne sont prêts* has no strong negative meaning. The sentence might have been written:

> Moins que jamais, ces pays sont prêts...

but that would have been less elegant. *Moins que jamais* is kind of a shortcut of *aujourd'hui moins que jamais* so another way to write the sentence that provides an explanation to the *ne* presence can be:

> Aujourd'hui, ces pays ne sont pas prêts à renoncer à une intégration nucléaire, et c'est encore plus le cas que ça ne l'a jamais été.

Should have the sentence started with *plus que jamais*, it would have read:

> *Plus que jamais, ces pays sont prêts à renoncer à...*

the opposite of the original meaning.

Answer (score 0):

"moins que jamais" is clearly not a common use for "jamais".
it might not be a mistake on the grammatical side, but it sounds terrible.

Comment: Sounds terrible? Racine, Boileau, La Bruyère, Mirabeau, Voltaire and others would turn in their grave...

Comment: this sounds terrible in the current usage of French, very old fashioned. But yes, it depends if the OP is looking for this kind of dated style

Comment: @TyKayn You are right insofar  as this form is used very little in [comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moins+que+jamais%2Cplus+que+jamais&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmoins%20que%20jamais%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplus%20que%20jamais%3B%2Cc0). D'ailleurs, cette différence est bizarre, plutôt arbitraire ; quel critère existe pour trouver cette forme désagréable ? Il faut avoir l'esprit assez « flexible ».